# Exporting a contact folder doesn't export all contacts Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, export, contacts

I'm having a weird problem. I have copied a public folder full of contact groups to my mailbox, then have exported it from there to a .csv file. The .csv file has 18 lines in it, one is a unique contact group (although they are called Contacts and only display one email address per line where each group contains multiple emails), but the original folder has 489 contact groups in it. I can't see what's different between the groups that have exported (albeit not exactly as I wanted) to the contact groups.

If I export to PST, then attach the PST to outlook, I can see all the contact group, and I can see the contacts within the contact groups, but when I double click any contact I get an error saying that the contact could not be found, could have been moved or deleted and would be removed from the group. Opening the contacts in the original location and in the temporary location that I had copied the folder to are both fine.

Any ideas what's going on?

Windows 7 32 bit, 32 bit Office (Outlook) 2010

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Contact Groups hold contacts from Public Folders (no actual contact info, just "links"). So, when you copied Contact Groups, you got links only with no additional info. You need to export Contact Groups from the original place (or from the place where you can access contained contacts).

Comment: I'm unable to export the original public folder as Outlook only lets you export from your own mailbox, and the copy of the public folder in my mailbox allows me to access all the contacts like I can in the public folder. Exporting to a PST and attaching the PST to the same mailbox where the original folder was copied gives me the missing contact errors, even though that mailbox has access to the original contact link sources as proven by the copied folder working.